# second if statement returns result, first if statement doesn't

Tags: python, debugging

In the code below, the when check_result returns true, I want my program to terminate.
However, when check_result(p1) returns `True` the print statement prints, but the program carries on.

BUT if check_result(p2) returns `True`, the statement gets printed and program terminates. Please help me figure out why the first one doesn't work
Thanks!

```
while game_on:

        p1_turn = int(input(f"Player 1, choose a number between 1 and 9\n"))
        matrix[p1_turn - 1] = "X"
        p1.append(p1_turn)
        place_mark(matrix)
        if check_result(p1):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            game_on = False

        p2_turn = int(input(f"Player 2, choose a number between 1 and 9\n"))
        matrix[p2_turn - 1] = "0"
        p2.append(p2_turn)
        place_mark(matrix)
        if check_result(p2):
            print("Player 2 wins")
            game_on = False
```

Comment: Your code asks for player 2 input, regardless of the result of `check_result(p1)`. Either break out of the loop or ask for player 2 input in an else clause.

Comment: Put a `break` in the if-statement clause. That will terminate the while loop. If you do the same for p2, you don't even need the `game_on` variable, and can just use `while True:`.

Comment: use while 1, it's slightly faster to use integers instead of booleans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while game_on:
        p1_turn = int(input(f"Player 1, choose a number between 1 and 9\n"))
        matrix[p1_turn - 1] = "X"
        p1.append(p1_turn)
        place_mark(matrix)
        if check_result(p1):
            print("Player 1 wins")
            game_on = False
            break
        p2_turn = int(input(f"Player 2, choose a number between 1 and 9\n"))
        matrix[p2_turn - 1] = "0"
        p2.append(p2_turn)
        place_mark(matrix)
        if check_result(p2):
            print("Player 2 wins")
            game_on = False
```

Just add the break statement, which will be implemented if Player 1 wins, which sets  the game_on as false and terminates the loop.

 Your code works for the case when Player 2 wins, so this is the only required change

Answer (score 0):

just put a break statement. and the game_on variable is uneccessary. just use `while 1` that is slightly faster than `while True`.

```
while 1:
    p1_turn = int(input(f"Player 1, choose a number between 1 and 9\n"))
    matrix[p1_turn - 1] = "X"
    p1.append(p1_turn)
    place_mark(matrix)
    if check_result(p1):
        print("Player 1 wins")
        break

    p2_turn = int(input(f"Player 2, choose a number between 1 and 9\n"))
    matrix[p2_turn - 1] = "0"
    p2.append(p2_turn)
    place_mark(matrix)
    if check_result(p2):
        print("Player 2 wins")
        break
```

Comment: Using while 1 instead of while True won't affect your performance by more than 0.000001s, that's an unnecessary change

Comment: i said *slightly* and anyway i always try to optimize as much as i can

Comment: Notice that in Python 2.x True was a costant declared to 1, so there wasn't even a *slight* difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
if check_result(p1):
    print("Player 1 wins")
    game_on = False
```

Do you see any `break` statement here? The `while` loop won't break by itself.

```
if check_result(p1):
    print("Player 1 wins")
    game_on = False
    break
```

---

You can anyway completely replace this `game_on` variable with a `break` statement:

```
if check_result(p1):
    print("Player 1 wins")
    break

if check_result(p2):
    print("Player 2 wins")
    break
```

---

If you want to know better the usage of `break` (and maybe of `continue`) read [`this`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue).